# SugarCRM Linking Contact Emails and Meetings with Accounts

Tags: crm, sugarcrm

Within SugarCRM, I have Accounts and Contacts. Each contact belongs to an account. I also have my Outlook Email linked to SugarCRM, so that when I email a contact or create a meeting I can Sync with Sugar.

The issue is that those emails or meetings will sync into the Contact record, but does not also carry across into the Account. Is there anyway to do this? Been searching for hours.

Comment: What Outlook Plugin are you using? What version of Sugar, and is it CE or Professional? By default, the Accounts History subpanel does pull all emails from Accounts' Contacts' Email Addresses.

Comment: Outlook plugin is "Sugar Plug-in for Outlook 2010 32bit", Sugar Version SugarCRM Professional, Version 7.1.5. Not sure why historic emails and calender entries are not carrying across into the Account from the Contact.

Comment: A, Sugar7. Check something for me - go to the Account and look in the "Intellegence Pane" on the right of the screen, and look into the History widget, and see if your logged email is listed there. I have a customer experiencing a similar issue currently and already have a case open with Sugar's internal team. You *may* have the same issue.

Comment: Hi. Yes the emails are pulling through into the History widget, under the emails tab, but they are not pulling through into the main sub panel. Thanks

Comment: Understood. I think this is an issue with Sugar7. I have an existing case with SugarCRM Support about it and I recommend you make one as well. http://www.sugarcrm.com/support/portal - click Login at the top right and create a new account if you don't already have one. You'll likely get added to an existing bug or feature request, so if a patch becomes available it'll be provided to you. You should also be able to reach out to your vendor to make support requests like this, and if you don't already have a vendor you're welcome to email me and we can chat outside of SO ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with SugarCRM 7.1.5, as defined in the bug report at http://www.sugarcrm.com/support/bugs.html?caseID=67265#issue_67265. I recommend you add comments and notes to this existing bug report. It may also help to file a separate Support Case (http://www.sugarcrm.com/support/portal) stating your issue and that you believe it to be a bug and ask for assistance. Every complaint raises visibility of the issue.